# Substitute all except last block

Tags: bash, sed

I have this file:

```
blog.miau.com
api.blog.miau.com
api.nano.miau.uk
willifox.dev.puton.com
```

And I want this output:

```
blog-miau.com
api-blog-miau.com
api-nan-.miau.uk
willifox-dev-puton.com
```

How can I achieve it, I do it with sed, but I substitute all . by -, and I want to leave the last . without replacement. Thanks

Comment: What about `api.nano.miau.co.uk`?  Should it be `api-nano-miau.co.uk`?

Comment: Is `api-nan-.miau.uk` in the output a typo? If so fix it, if not explain it.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` that should do:

```
sed 's/\./-/g;s/\(.*\)-/\1\./' file
blog-miau.com
api-blog-miau.com
api-nano-miau.uk
willifox-dev-puton.com
```

- `s/#/\./` replace all `.` with `-`
- `s/\(.*\)-/\1#/` replace last `-` with `.`

Comment: What if there are one or more `-`'s following the last `.` e.g. `a.b.c.x-y-z` ?

Comment: @potong What if the earth is flat?  What if there are `www.bbc.co.uk` that should be `www-bbc.co.uk` etc. Its up to OP to respond if the solution cover his/her needs ;)

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but remember other people will read the heading of this question and perhaps not the detail. There is an inherent flaw in the logic of this answer and as programmers we like to cover off all corner cases to make bullet proof solutions. With a couple of tweaks this can easily be achieved e.g. `sed 'y/.-/-\n/;s/\(.*\)-/\1./;y/\n/-/' file`